# SUM in a while loop - php

Tags: php, while-loop, sum

I have a loop which extracts 2 numbers from a table and then calculates the total.

I want to find the final total (sum of all totals).

Is there a way to not use the DB to calculate the SUM but do it within the loop.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

   $total= $row["num1"] + $row["num2"];

}
```

How do I do this?

This is wrong:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

   $total= $row["num1"] + $row["num2"];

   $total = $total + $total;

}
```

Comment: In the first attempt you reassign `$total` each iteration, but of course you want to add the new values in each iteration. In the second attempt the same, just that you added another line, where you double the value, but still reassign it. Also make sure to initialize the variable before the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$total=0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

   $sum= $row["num1"] + $row["num2"];

   $total = $total + $sum;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply initialize your `$total` outside the `while` Loop to zero and then add to it like so:

```
<?php

    $total     = 0;

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $total += ($row["num1"] + $row["num2"]);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add to the overall total with each iteration of the loop:

```
<?php 
$total = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $total += $row['num1'] + $row['num2'];
}
```

Actually in php you are not even required to initialize the `$total` variable as shown, but it is considered good practice, since it raises the readability of the code.

Doing this on the level of a scripting language obviously is much less efficient than using the db engine itself to calculate the sum. But I assume this is not a real works task, but some seminar homework or similar...

Answer (score 0):

```
$total = 0;

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $total += $row["num1"] + $row["num2"];
}
```